# Illegal access to loading collection in Fluent and Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm not able to understand why the problem is occurring. Please let me know if there are any errors, I am very new to this topic.

```
public class Department
{
    public virtual int Dept_id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Dept_name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public Department()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
}
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    { 

    }
    //private int _Dept_id;
    //public virtual Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    /*public virtual int Dept_id
    {
        get { return this._Dept_id; }
        set { this._Dept_id = value; }
    }*/
    public virtual int Dept_id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual String Address { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
public class DepartmentMap : ClassMap<Department>
{
    public DepartmentMap()
    {
        Table("Department");
        Id(x => x.Dept_id).Column("Dept_id");
        Map(x => x.Dept_name).Column("Dept_name");

        HasMany(x => x.Students).KeyColumn("Student_id").Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();

    }
}
public class StudentMap :ClassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap() 
    {
        Table("Student");
        Id(x => x.StudentId).Column("Student_id").GeneratedBy.GuidComb();  

        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Age);
        Map(x => x.Address);         

        References(x => x.Department).Column("Dept_id")
            .Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying this code

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public List<Student> Students()
    {
        IList<Student> student = new List<Student>();
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();
        student = session.Query<Student>().ToList();

        return student.ToList();
    }
```

it gives error in loading the students list inside the department as

> illegal access to loading collection

What is lacking in this code and why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

sorry my bad !! there are cetain changes i made which made it working .. though not sure of apparent shortcomings of the mentioned idea below

changed student class as :

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    { 

    }

    public virtual Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual int Dept_id
    {
        get { return Department.Dept_id; }
        set { this.Dept_id = Department.Dept_id; }
    }

    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual String Address { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

and student mapping for the reference as

> References(x => x.Department).Column("Dept_id").Cascade.All();

Note : there should be no single Dept Id mapping

and changed the DepartmentMap as :

```
public DepartmentMap()
    {
        Table("Department");
        Id(x => x.Dept_id).Column("Dept_id");
        Map(x => x.Dept_name).Column("Dept_name");


        HasMany(x => x.Students).KeyColumn("Dept_id").AsBag();

    }
```